# Youtube API - Grab screenshot of a video at a specific time

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am looking to generate a high definition screenshot of youtube video at a specific time. Say I have the Youtube video ID (ctiJc4yEVow) and I want a screenshot of what appears at 1:32. Is there a clean and easy to implement way to do that? I have read way of using ffmpeg and some misc sloppy code, but nothing reliable.

The only thing I have seen is how to generate an image for a video, unspecific to any time.

https://i1.ytimg.com/vi//default.jpg

My issue is I need a specific time. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any way to do this within the official API. Their [Videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and [Thumbnails](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails)
pages don't offer any way to do this.

That said, you could link to the time you want, then screenshot that. This would work best with YouTube's autoplay turned off. Example link based on your post: youtube.com/watch?v=ctiJc4yEVow&t=1m32s

Comment: Are there any updated answers for this? Would love to know.